# How to add several directives to a single component

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, plunker

Hello first of all I must say I am sorry but I don't know how to express the question better, is the reason I am not being able to find an answer by myself.

What I'm talking about is how to load a component inside another one, I need to indicate it in the directive. Here is a very small example that I did from scratch because I am not able to find the right syntax:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gFsqGJmmayOsewL3EfLf

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'
import {Prueba} from './prueba'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <prueba></prueba>      
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [Prueba]
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

So as you can see in app.ts there is a directives inside component, if I remove that it does not work. I am not 100% sure why, but it's how I learned.

So next step, I wanted to have several components, so I can have Prueba and another that adds something extra (for starters, another "phrase", but the idea is to add something similar to THIS: http://plnkr.co/edit/SVPNwk?p=preview ). However I find myself unable to find the right syntax, anything I try makes even this simple example to fail.

As I said, I do not understand what am I missing, I have a new component, I import it, I use the selector, and so on, but it simply explodes. What concepts am I missing?

If I am still not explaining myself properly enough, this is the theoric concept I am talking about:

angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cheatsheet.html   (I cannot post more than two links... anyway its the @Component part, that's the documentation I'm checking out).

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. What do you exactly mean by "if I remove that it does not work.". If you remove "<prueba></prueba>" or "directives: [Prueba]"?

Comment: what you realy want to do ? and whats the error you got ?

Comment: I am sorry you are correct it isn't clear @ThierryTemplier . I meant if I remove Prueba from "directives: [Prueba]", it ends up not showing anything (which as far as I know, it is expected).

Comment: What I really want to do @PardeepJain is to be able to add that calendar I showed, because I know it DOES work, to an existing project. I am finding myself unable to do it, and as far as I got, is because of directives (when, it really shouldn't be the problem, since what little documentation I've found points to directives being an array, so it should accept multiple directives).

Comment: This is your starting point https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/

Comment: @monkeyintern Yes that's the normal behavior when you remove from the `directives` attribute. What is this calendar component? Did you try to add its class within this attribute and use it in your `App` component using the calendar component selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular2 there is a difference between a component and a directive:

- A **component** gathers a view (template) with some properties and processing (the component class)
- There are two kinds of directives:

  - **Attribute directive**. It changes the appearance or behavior of a DOM element
  - **Structural directive**. It changes the DOM layout by adding and removing DOM elements.

A component can be used in another component using its selector. You need to explicitly define it in the `directives` attribute of the container component. Whereas the attribute is called `directives`, you can put in it both components and directives. You can also provide parameters to a component and react on its events.

Here is a sample:

- Sub component

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'sub',
    template: `
      <div>Sub</div>
    `
  })
  export class SubComponent {
  }
  ```
- Container component:

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'comp',
    template: `
      <div>
        <sub></sub>
      </div>
    `,
    directives: [ SubComponent, AnotherComponent ]
  })
  export class ContainerComponent {
  }
  ```

A directive will apply on an existing element also based on it selector.

Here is a sample:

- Sub component

  ```
  @Directive({
    selector: '[dir]'
  })
  export class DirDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
      // el.nativeElement corresponds to the DOM element
      // the directive applies on
      el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
  }
  ```
- Container component:

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'comp',
    template: `
      <div dir>Some text</div>
    `,
    directives: [ DirDirective ]
  })
  export class ContainerComponent {
  }
  ```

**The `directives` attribute**

To tell a bit more about the `directives` attribute. If the component / directive isn't a platform one, you need to explicitly define into this directive. If not, the component / directive won't apply.

This attribute can accept several values since it's an array:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'comp',
  template: `
    <div>
      <sub></sub>
      <another></another>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ SubComponent, AnotherComponent ]
})
export class ContainerComponent {
}
```

Comment: I see. I knew some of this (because of the documentation) but not all, I think I have a way better grasp of it so thank you! Problem must be somewhere else if it IS possible to add several directives on a given Component.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes you can have / use several components / directives into a component...

Comment: The `directives` attribute doesn't seem to be there in Angular 4 anymore.